# how to export several .xls (Excel) files in a directory into a single .csv file?

Tags: .net, csv, xls

So I'm looking for a way to export all of the .xls files in a directory into a single .csv file. Any ideas as to how I would approach this?

Specifically:

say my directory contains-

```
wksht1.xls
wksht2.xls
wksht3.xls
...
wksht1000.xls
```

how would I merge all of those files into a single .csv (We'll call is aggregate.csv).
Assume each file has the maximum amount of worksheets/rows filled.

*All of the files are normalized to a data standard*

Thank you very much!

Comment: all excel files have the same columns ?

Comment: It can be anything than can run on a Microsoft machine (java, python, etc...)

Comment: Seems to be a nice job for PowerShell.

Comment: yes, all excel files are normalized

Comment: I was thinking about powershell, but I couldn't figure out how to make a bash script that does the conversion. I was toying with the idea of a batch that calls a vba script, but that seems too complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the NON .NET solution (it's not clear if your ".NET" tag implies that .NET is mandatory).

I'd write a VBS/WSH script like this one and run it from the command line:

```
Dim oFSO
Dim oShell, oExcel, oFile, oSheet
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder("C:\").Files
  If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) = "xls" Then
    With oExcel.Workbooks.Open(oFile, 0, True, , , , True, , , , False, , False)
      For Each oSheet In .Worksheets
        oSheet.SaveAs ".\" & oFile.Name & "." & oSheet.Name, 6
      Next
      .Close False, , False
    End With
  End If
Next
oExcel.Quit
oShell.Popup "Conversion complete", 10
```

Mind you, this is directly excerpted from here: http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/script-convert-excel-ss-to-csv/16265.html

But I've used a nearly identical approach many times before to export Access tables to CSV, so I know that VBS scripting is a viable (and probably the simplest) method for this.

Modify the directory name as you see fit (i.e. I don't think your files are in "C:\".  Save this to a file named `export_to_csv.vbs`, then run with:

```
cscript export_to_csv.vbs
```

or

```
wscript export_to_csv.vbs
```